# How to get the information about the page that call .cfc page and function? ColdFusion9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have global function in my system that was implemented while ago before I even started maintaining the system. One of the recent projects involved some major updates in that function. I have set the cfmail with some information inside in hope that I will get the .cfm page that call that function. So far only that I got is the page where the function is located but I already knew that. I got this information with this function:

```
GetDirectoryFromPath(path)
```

I was wondering if there is any other function that can give me the name of the page that called the function? If anyone can help me solve this problem please let me know. I'm still doing research but there is nothing that I came accross that would be helpful in my case.

Comment: Have you tried this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674619/find-whos-calling-the-method

Comment: It's not clear how to implement that code and I'm not sure if that will work in CF9. If you can provide any example that would be great. Thank you @Soobax

Comment: what you really want? you want to know whether other files use the function you use?

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use CF9 and did this:

In a CFC

```
<cffunction name="dumpCGI" returntype="void" output="yes">
<cfdump var="#cgi#">
</cffunction>
```

In the calling template:

```
obj = createObject("component", "Something");
obj.dumpCGI();
```

I saw 3 variables that correctly identified the calling template.  Once you pick the one you want to use, you can decide how to process it.

Comment: I ended up using  #CGI.HTTP_REFERER#. That gave me the template name. CGI in general gives you everything you need I guess. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would have gone with path_translated, path_info, or cf_template_path.  If you have a form or url that leads to the page calling the cfc, http_referrer will probably not be what you want.

Comment: Only HTTP_REFERER gave the information about the page from where my function was called. path_translated just gave the page where cffunction is located that I already know. Path_Info is empty for some reason. I will keep looking if this will give me different information later on.

Comment: Your results were different than mine.  I recommend that you test the scenario where the page calling the function is itself accessed by a form or hyperlink.